# Time Domain / Spectrum / DSP

Tags: matlab, numpy, fft, ifft

I perform an iFFT on a complex-valued spectrum and change the corresponding time domain-signal by lets say nulling the first sample. Finally I transform it back to frequency domain via FFT.

I wonder where is the (physically) difference between using the two-sided (symmetric) spectrum, or only the one-sided spectrum (positive frequencies only) here, since the two results are different (while comparing the positive frequencies)?

Version 1 (two-sided spectrum):
`fft(
        nulling(
                ifft( [0, 1+1j, 2+j, 2-2j, 1-1j] )
                )
        )`

Output:
    [-1.2, -0.2+1j,  0.8+2j,  0.8-2j, -0.2-1j]

Version 2 (one-sided spectrum):
`fft(
        nulling(
                ifft( [0, 1+1j, 2+j] )
                )
        )`

Output:
    [ -1-1j,  0+0j, 1+1j]

Answer (score 3):

Since your IFFT routine doesn't *know* that you are supplying a one-sided spectrum (ie. that there are implicit complex conjugate symmetric negative frequency bins) it can only (mis-)interpret this as a normal N point complex frequency domain input with both positive and negative frequency bins.

Some FFT libraries (e.g. FFTW, vDSP) *do* support real-to-complex FFT and complex-to-real IFFT, where the number of complex frequency domain bins is N / 2 and the redundant complex conjugate symmetric terms are omitted, but they typically have a separate API for this which is different from the more general complex-to-complex case with N inputs and N outputs.

Comment: this means one should always extend a one-sided spectrum to a two-sided spectrum prior to iFFT for the purposes of performing time-domain manipulations?

Comment: Yes - if you only have the more common complex-to-complex IFFT available then you will need to take care of the negative frequency bins yourself.

Comment: And as a side note, the relevant function to return/operate on a one-sided spectrum in numpy is `np.fft.rfft` and `np.fft.irfft`.

Comment: @Joe: good catch - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html#numpy.fft.irfft appears to be a more convenient solution for complex-to-real IFFT

Comment: Julia also has this capability `irfft` https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/math/#Base.DFT.irfft